# Rendering React components according to Amplify logged in user

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

How can I render different React components based on the output of `Amplify.currentAuthenticatedUser()` (or similar equivalent) ?

The following works -

```
render() {
    if (Auth.user) {
        return (
        <LoggedInContainer pages={this.state.pages} />
        );
    } else {
        return (
        <LoginForm loginHandler={this.login} />
        );
    };
}
```

but if I refresh the page the session seems to be lost and I have to re- login, ie I think referencing `Auth.user` is sub- optimal.

If I try the following -

```
render() {
    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then(user => {
        return (
        <LoggedInContainer pages={this.state.pages} />
        );
    }).catch(e => {
        return (
        <LoginForm loginHandler={this.login} />
        );
    });
}
```

then I get `Your render method should have return statement  react/require-render-return`

If I try the following -

```
getCurrentUser() {
    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then(user => {
        console.log(user.attributes.email);
        return user.attributes.email;
    }).catch(e => {
        return undefined;
    });
}
render() {
    if (this.getCurrentUser()) {
        return (
        <LoggedInContainer pages={this.state.pages} />
        );
    } else {
        return (
        <LoginForm loginHandler={this.login} />
        );
    };
}
```

then I never get logged in because the output of `getCurrentUser` is always `undefined`, *despite* the fact that the `console.log()` line in `getCurrentUser` prints out the correct email of the user!

Is there no simple way to get the value of the current Amplify logged- in user, and render different React components according to its value ?

Comment: Im trying to get a better understanding of your question, so you are using the function `this.getCurrentUser()` to see if the user is authenticated right? I see you are trying to return user data in this function but this data is never passed or used, or am I overlooking something here? I'll update with an answer in a bit

Comment: trying to get some kind of value out of `Auth.getCurrentUser()` rather than a Promise, so I can render React components depending on whether that value is undefined or not

Comment: I think upon further reading that the solution may require the js async / await construct (which is supported by react)

Comment: I posted an answer. Instead of using promises you could use `async/await` but the logic of rendering different components based on `Auth.getCurrentUser()` would stay the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use a `switch` statement in combination with an `enum` when I'm dealing with rendering different components based on state/value. The `switch` deals with rendering the correct component and the `enum` values are used to give values to the cases of the switch statement.

What happens in this component:

1. The component uses 2 state values: `authStatus` and `user`, both set to the default value.
2. `ComponentDidMount()` gets launched after the initial render and `getCurrentUser()` is launched here.
3. In `getCurrentUser()` we set the state depending on the outcome of this function. This state will be used for rendering the correct component.
4. In `render()`the `switch` statement will be launched and we use our `authStatus` state value for rendering the correct component.

Note: You are dealing with an async request, when none of the cases in the `switch` are matched it will render the default case which in my case will render null, this is something you would want to avoid and instead atleast render a load icon or give the user some feedback to what is happening. I created another `enum` called `ProgressStatus` that can help you with this, you would use this `enum` the same way in a `switch` statement as the one below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export enum AuthStatus {
  isLoggedIn = "isLoggedIn",
  isNotLoggedIn = "isNotLoggedIn",
  Uninitialized = "uninitialized"
}

export enum ProgressStatus {
  InProgress = "InProgress",
  Uninitialized = "Uninitialized",
  Done = "Done",
  Error = "Error"
}

class AuthenticationShell extends Component {

  state = {
    authStatus: AuthStatus.Uninitialized,
    user: undefined
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    // this function will launch when the component is mounted to the dom
    this.getCurrentUser()
  }

  getCurrentUser = () => {
    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then(user => {
      // if user is authenticated update authStatus & user state here
      this.setState({
        authStatus: AuthStatus.isLoggedIn,
        user: user.attributes.email
      })
    }).catch(e => {
      // if user is not authenticated update authStatus
      this.setState({ authStatus: AuthStatus.isNotLoggedIn })
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { authStatus } = this.state;
    switch (authStatus) {
      case AuthStatus.isLoggedIn:
        return (
          <div>
            <LoggedInContainer />
          </div>
        )
      case AuthStatus.isNotLoggedIn:
        return (
          <div>
            <LoginForm />
          </div>
        )
      default: return null;
      // when authstatus is Uninitialized or not isLoggedIn and not isNotLoggedIn null will be rendered
      // Rendering null while waiting on some async function is not ideal
    }
  }
}

export default AuthenticationShell;
```

Comment: OK that works, thanks - the bit I missed was that you can't render off the output of the promise directly (`user`), you have to save it to state first